# merging two data frames failed in R

Tags: r

1st data frame:

```
> head(rawCountTable)
          X1916.MJO.0001_1 X1916.MJO.0002_1 X1916.MJO.0003_1 X1916.MJO.0004_1 X1916.MJO.0005_1 X1916.MJO.0006_1
sp0055008                9                5               10                2               13               18
sp0052637               32               16               27               18               25               28
sp0025247               50               73               67               63               94               73
sp0025250                9                5                5               17               15               22
sp0025268              141              117              107              104              129              135
sp0025270                0                0                0                0                0                0
```

2nd data frame

```
> head(gene.description)
          V1                                                V6
1: sp0082943                                       Exonuclease
2: sp0086614                                     NB-ARC domain
3: sp0013196 Ulp1 protease family, C-terminal catalytic domain
4: sp0088665                     Ankyrin repeats (many copies)
5: sp0071721                            Peptidase inhibitor I9
6: sp0012855         Ubiquitin fusion degradation protein UFD1
```

During merging I got the following error:

```
> merge(rownames(rawCountTable),gene.description, by.y="V1")
Error in merge.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), as.data.frame(y), ...)
```

I needed to merger the two data frames together because

```
> dim(rawCountTable)
[1] 94003    24
> dim(gene.description)
[1] 61125     2
```

I need all 94003 ids. What did I miss?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try changing your merge statement to: `merge(data.frame(V1=rownames(rawCountTable)),gene.description)`? If you are trying to merge only the `rownames` from `rawCountTable`

Comment: `dim(merge(data.frame(V1=rownames(rawCountTable)),gene.description)) ` produced  (61125     2 ) and not 94003. How can I get all `V1=rownames(rawCountTable))` values in the merged data frame. Yes I need only the `rownames` from `rawCountTable`.

Comment: add `all.x = TRUE` in your merge parameters, you're trying to do a left join